# How to reduce Image sizes while loading network image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, image-compression

I don't know how to reduce the size of Image in flutter while loading. We have many packages to reduce the size while uploading image but for loading profile images or for a small images in grid view It takes so much time to load the image.

Comment: This should be in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's easy from flutter. Maybe you can try some services like [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations)